# How do I stop eclipse from aligning on columns when breaking arrays?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm trying to break a long array that I'm giving as an input to a function in some javascript code. When I do this, eclipse is aligning the broken part of the array with the first open `[` in the code, so that my code looks like this

```
myObject.method(arg1, [some.very.long.argument - something.else,
                       another.argument.that.i.dont.want.on.the.same.line]);
```

The problem with this is that eclipse is using spaces to achieve this indentation, and I've been indenting everything with tabs because I like the way tabs look.

How do I make eclipse stop mixing spaces into my tabs with the auto align to column behavior?

'Switch to using spaces' is not an acceptable answer.

Currently, I'm manually putting a semicolon at the end of the first line, tabbing the second one how I want (which is one tab more than the first), and then deleting the semicolon. It's rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences -> JavaScript -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> Indentation = Tabs Only

Comment: I already had this set. It doesn't stop eclipse from mixing spaces in when it aligns columns.